# How to drop table from code behind file if session expire?

Tags: asp.net

I am creating table in actual database,base on sessionid of user in button1 click event and adding record into it and in button2 click event, I doing some processing and finally droping that table.It is working fine.

But if user does not click on button2 or  move to another page or session expire or user close browser,in above secanario my table exist as it as in database.How can I drop that table?

I can't create temp table.If my sql connection closes temp table automatically get dropped.Here I am fetching record from grid that have paging.If user select some record from page one and click on button1,table get created and record get added into that table,when user move to second page and select record,that record get added into table.

Comment: Kindly don't post question as paragraph it very difficult to read it out.

Comment: If you don't want to use local as well as global temp tables, then may be you can create table in the tempDb, it will be removed when the server is restarted.

Comment: Suprabhat can u pls read question properly? I am not creating separate table for paging...

Comment: Sorry, My mistake when you posted the question in form of paragraph it seems like your were creating a separating table.